# How do I transfer Solana from any wallet using web3.js?

Tags: web3.js, phantom

I'm struggling to find any working examples that are not deprecated. If anyone can direct me towards any that would be great.

For learning purposes I want to setup a button that will send 1 Solana from a connected wallet to a user-specified recipient address.

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Comment: check out the dapp-scaffold, there is a component you can reference for sending SOL: https://github.com/solana-labs/dapp-scaffold/blob/main/src/components/SendTransaction.tsx

Comment: You can check Solana Cookbook. Code samples here are pretty good and up-to-date. https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#how-to-send-sol

Answer (score 2):

To send SOL with a button, here's an example using the [dapp-scaffold](https://github.com/solana-labs/dapp-scaffold):

```
import { WalletNotConnectedError } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-base";
import { useConnection, useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react";
import { Keypair, SystemProgram, Transaction } from "@solana/web3.js";
import React, { FC, useCallback } from "react";

export const SendLamportsToRandomAddress: FC = () => {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { publicKey, sendTransaction } = useWallet();

  const onClick = useCallback(async () => {
    if (!publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();

    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: publicKey,
        toPubkey: Keypair.generate().publicKey,
        lamports: 1_000_000,
      })
    );

    const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, connection);

    await connection.confirmTransaction(signature, "processed");
  }, [publicKey, sendTransaction, connection]);

  return (
    <button onClick={onClick} disabled={!publicKey}>
      Send lamports to a random address!
    </button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Solana's Wallet Adapter for React has multiple starters on the [Github Repo](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/starter); you can use that and the example on the [README](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/master/README.md) to connect a wallet and create that button that sends a transaction.

There's also other packages for other frontend frameworks made by the community:

- [Vue](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter#:%7E:text=additional%20frontend%20frameworks.-,Vue,-Angular)
- [Svelte](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter#:%7E:text=Angular-,Svelte,-Build%20from%20Source)
- [Angular](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter#:%7E:text=Vue-,Angular,-Svelte)